opentelemtry exports previous custom metrics every 10 sec
I have a .NET application configured to export custom metrics using the OpenTelemetry SDK to Application Insights. I’ve noticed that even when metrics aren’t updated, OpenTelemetry still pushes the previous metrics to Application Insights. This issue prevents us from accurately calculating the values. If this is a default feature, how can we obtain the correct data using a KQL query?
